# IOS crash when closing a modal in expo managed project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

Expo managed project on ios

When my app starts, there is a modal showing up with a button to access the app without any account. The crashs happen when clicking on this button. The correct beahvior is to close the modal.

When I test in a development build and in testflight it works fine but when it is reviewed it crashes. I didn't manage to reproduce the issue on an iPad or an iPhone. Here is one of the crash reports that I received :

```js
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "ktriageinfo" : "VM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\n",
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":601372,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":216,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":85732,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":941832,"symbol":"__CFDictionaryCreateGeneric","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4919592,"symbol":"-[UIView(Hierarchy) _associatedViewControllerForwardsAppearanceCallbacks:performHierarchyCheck:isRoot:]","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":4109060,"symbol":"-[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:]","symbolLocation":244,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1545712,"symbol":"-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]","symbolLocation":432,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2486960,"symbol":"-[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:]","symbolLocation":1336,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2880572,"symbol":"-[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]","symbolLocation":1496,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":4759516,"symbol":"___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2","symbolLocation":72,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2917644,"symbol":"+[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:]","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":3387600,"symbol":"___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.641","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":3939216,"symbol":"+[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]","symbolLocation":172,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2511492,"symbol":"_UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":8979416,"symbol":"__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.401","symbolLocation":2152,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":3195456,"symbol":"-[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2258800,"symbol":"-[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush]","symbolLocation":200,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1400496,"symbol":"_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks","symbolLocation":640,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1402236,"symbol":"_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks","symbolLocation":128,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1402696,"symbol":"_afterCACommitHandler","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":256060,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":64116,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoObservers","symbolLocation":616,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":45052,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1012,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":123472,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6536,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":5134996,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":1080,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2617300,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":336,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":21672,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":99536,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":444,"imageIndex":9}],
```

I have difficulties in understanding this report. I understood that it is a language exception but couldn't find anything more. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-language-exception-crashes

```js
<Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={false}
        visible={!this.props.estConnecte}>
        <View style={styles.accueilView}>
          <ImageBackground resizeMode="cover" style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', padding:50}} source={require('../assets/splash.png')}>

          <Button1 onPress={() => this.displayLogin()} title = {"Se connecter"} styleSup = {{color: COLORS.iconesView}}/>
          <Button1 onPress={() => this.creerCompte()} title = {"Créer un compte"} styleSup = {{color: COLORS.iconesView}}/>
          <Button1 onPress={() => this.accesSansCompte()} title = {"Accès sans compte"} styleSup = {{color: COLORS.iconesView}}/>
          <View style={{flex:0.1}}/>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
        <Login/>
        <Signin/>
      </Modal>
```

The function this.accesSansCompte() only changes the state of this.props.estConnecte.

I have tried to add a timeout before closing the modal without any success. Any idea is greatly appreciated ! Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue came from the modal component itself as suggested here :

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/944#issuecomment-971559549

I installed the package react-native-modal instead of using the standard Modal:

https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal

I used it only on my very first login modal displayed at the start of the app and it works just fine !

No need to use Timeout or anything else.